# Microsoft Appfabric configuration to SQL server

Tags: appfabric-cache

We are getting the below error when trying to Configure App fabric.

1. We create a empty database
2. Provide userID who is running the configuration sysadmin access on the sql server
3. The last step in the configuration  shows this error. Looks like the machine specific SQL id is not getting created for the AppFabricCache database.

> Could not set permissions on configuration Store: ErrorCode:Substatus : No such host is known. Refer to product documentation for manually configuring the store permissions

[image]